# Command curl not found, even though it is installed

Tags: linux, curl, path, binary

First I've installed `curl`:

```
company@rb-VirtualBox:~$ apt install curl
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

company@rb-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt install curl
[sudo] password for company: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 552 not upgraded.
```

Then I tried to use it:

```
company@rb-VirtualBox:~$ ​curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'

Command '​curl' not found, did you mean:

  command 'curl' from deb curl (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7)

Try: apt install <deb name>
```

As you can see it still says "Command '​curl' not found".

If I execute it with the full path like this:

```
company@rb-VirtualBox:~$ /usr/bin/curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

then it works

---

#### More Informations:

```
company@rb-VirtualBox:~$ whereis curl
curl: /usr/bin/curl /usr/share/man/man1/curl.1.gz

company@rb-VirtualBox:~$ echo $PATH
/home/company/.nvm/versions/node/v17.8.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: what if you try `​command curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'` or `\​curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'`?

Comment: For the first I get `command: command not found`, the second one throws the error `Command '​curl' not found`

Comment: What does `type -a curl` produce?

Comment: `curl is /usr/bin/curl`

Comment: strange.  I wonder if maybe there was some sort of special character involved when you first had the issue.  If you copied that full command from somewhere maybe it had a `\r` or something in it.

Comment: @jesse_b this could be true, I copied it from a website hosted in my companys network. Is there a way to see the raw clipboard content?

Comment: @jesse_b I just ocnfirmed it! You are right. If I copy it from the website again then it fails with the same error.

Comment: Are you using the `zsh` shell? The `zsh` shell caches the locations of all known commands, and when you install a new command, you have to re-cache the locations of all commands to pick up the new command.  You do that with `rehash` in that shell.  If you use the command with its full path, it would later remember the location of that command, so that would work too.

Comment: @Kusalananda, no I am working with "Terminator"

Comment: Terminator is a terminal, which is running a shell. What is that shell? What does, for example, `echo $SHELL`, output?

Comment: Oh I see, thx! I get `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but after calling it with

```
company@rb-VirtualBox:~$ /usr/bin/curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

now suddenly this works too:

```
company@rb-VirtualBox:~$ curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

**UPDATE:**

As @jesse_b assumed correctly in the comments, it is because I copied the command from a website and some fishy characters like `\r` or `\n` where included, which were causing the error.